# Is it possible to source a file in bash, but skipping specific functions?

Tags: bash, shell, function

Suppose I have `bash_functions.sh`:

```
function test(){
}

function test2(){
}
```

And in my `~/.bashrc` I do:

```
source ~/bash_functions.sh
```

Is it possible to, when sourcing it, avoid sourcing a specific function? I mean, source everything in `bash_functions.sh`, except for `test`?

Comment: @Somebody: Perhaps you could elaborate on your use case? What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Sometimes you're using bash_functions.sh from someone, and want everything there's there except for a few functions that you already have defined in your  own files and don't want them overriden.

Comment: @Somebody: couldn't you just comment out the ones you don't want?

Comment: @Faheem Mitha: this becomes unpractical over time if you use a bash_functions.sh that is versioned somewhere, and always do a checkout/pull from it.

Comment: @Somebody: Ok. I see. I guess keeping your diffs local and merging with upstream is not an option then?

Comment: @Faheem Mitha: I thougth about this option. If a 'skip function' solution would be easier than keepindg diffs local, I prefer. That's why I asked the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a function definition `foo () { … }`, if `foo` is an alias, it is expanded. This can sometimes be a problem, but here it helps. Alias `foo` to some other name before sourcing the file, and you'll be defining a different function. In bash, alias expansion is off by default in non-interactive shells, so you need to turn it on with `shopt -s expand_aliases`.

If `sourced.sh` contains

```
foo () {
  echo "foo from sourced.sh"
}
```

then you use it this way

```
foo () {
  echo "old foo"
}
shopt -s expand_aliases   # necessary in bash; just skip in ash/ksh/zsh
alias foo=do_not_define_foo
. sourced.sh
unalias foo; unset -f do_not_define_foo
foo
```

then you get `old foo`. Note that the sourced file must use the `foo () { … }` function definition syntax, not `function foo { … }`, because the `function` keyword would block alias expansion.

Comment: This seems to be an interesting approach, but I need the sourced scripts to be in the same foo () { ... } definition, right? I was thinking about putting all function names I didn't want to source in an array, and somehow "source" receive it and don't source them. Well, I think it's not going to be possible. Interesting hack, anyways!

Comment: @Somebody: I don't understand your comment. The function definitions need to be in the portable `foo ()` form and not in the ksh extension `function foo` form, but other than that you can effectively re-route any number of function definitions.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly, however, you can override the test() function.  The last function definition always takes precedence. So if you source a file that has `test()` then define a function with the same name after that, the latter function will override the one that was sourced. I take advantage of this to provide some object-orientedness in some of my scripts.

Example:

bash_functions.sh:

```
test(){
    echo "This is the test function from bash_functions."
}
test2(){
    echo "This is the test2 function from bash_functions."
}
```

scripty_scripterson.sh

```
test2(){
    #this is thrown in just to show what happens in
    #the other direction
    echo "This is the test2 function from scripty."
}

source bash_functions.sh

test1(){
    echo "This is the test1 function from scripty."
}

test1
test2
```

At the command line:

```
$ ./scripty_scripterson.sh 
This is the test1 function from scripty.
This is the test2 function from bash_functions.
```

Comment: I'm already doing this approach. :) But somehow it seens wrong to me, and in my use case, I have to soure my files, source the external bash_functions.sh and again source my files (since I use some functions from my files when sourcing bash_functions.sh)

Answer (score 1):

You may create a temp-file, read it in, and delete it afterwards. To delete function 'test', I assume here that there is no '}' inside the function.

```
sed '/test()/,/}/d' testrc > ./tmprc && source ./tmprc && rm tmprc
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. You can divide bash_functions.sh into 2 file, one include what you want to source, and another include the functions you don't want to source. and use a 3rd script file to combine them for normal usage.